# Loops and filling empty vectors in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I'm looking to fill in this empty vector:

```
empty_vec <- rep("", times=length(number_vec))
```

with sequential numbers from this loop:

```
for (numbers in number_vec) {   
  sqrtn <- sqrt(numbers)
  empty_vec[numbers] <- sqrtn
}
```

where `numbers_vec` is `c(16:49)`.

However, when I do this, the first positions (1-15) in my `empty_vec` are not filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can address this in two ways:

First, you can create a counter, that will register which step of the loop you are, and use this as index to `empty_vect`, like this:

```
empty_vec <- rep("", times=length(number_vec))
counter <- 0
for (numbers in number_vec) {   
  counter <- counter + 1
  sqrtn <- sqrt(numbers)
  empty_vec[counter] <- sqrtn
}
```

Or you can just create an empty vector and concatenate each new value, like this:

```
empty_vec <- c()
for (numbers in number_vec) {   
  sqrtn <- sqrt(numbers)
  empty_vec <- c(empty_vec, sqrtn)
}
```

The way you were doing, is like you started to fill your vector in 16th position, that's way you had error.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: I made an edit, cause I had commited a mistake. It's working now.

Comment: I did it both ways, but somehow R sees my empty vector as a function?

error in npv_r(current_nr_of_years) = temp : 
  could not find function "npv_r<-"

Comment: correction; your method 2 worked but your method 1 gave the error above

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how for loop works

General express for for loop is

```
for(var in seq) expr
    var =  A syntactical name for a variable
    seq =  An expression evaluating to a vector (including a list and an expression) or to a pairlist or NULL. A factor value will be coerced to a character vector.
```

so note it , "seq" will be the  value of the "var".

In your example , you wrote

```
for (numbers in number_vec)
where,
     numbers = Name of the variable
     number_vec = c(16:49)
```

So here , the initial value of "numbers" will be first value of "number_vec" which is 16.

in later step in loop, the expression

```
empty_vec[numbers]<-sqrt
where , 
    empty_vec[numbers] indicate the 16th position of the  empty_vec as initially numbers started with value 16
```

As you start with 16th position , the previous 15 position remain empty.

Possible solution of your problem :

```
number_vec = c(16:49)
empty_vec <- rep("", times=length(number_vec))

for (numbers in seq_along(number_vec)) {   
  sqrt<-sqrt(number_vec[numbers])
  empty_vec[numbers]<-sqrt
}
```